# Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header() error when using the Laravel excel package

Tags: php, laravel, export-to-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying laravel excel to export  with my data in xlsx format.

Regarding the data to be exported, I need to export the data with relationship.

here is my code

```
for the UserExport.php

<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Address;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UserInfo;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;


use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;


class UsersExport implements FromCollection,  WithMapping ,WithHeadings
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        $user = UserInfo::with('address')->get();
         return $user;
    }

    public function map($Userinfo): array
    {

        return [
              $Userinfo->id,
              $Userinfo->organizational_id_no,
              $Userinfo->last_name,
              $Userinfo->first_name,
              $Userinfo->middle_name,
              $Userinfo->cel_no,
              $Userinfo->tel_no,
              $Userinfo->work_position,
              $Userinfo->address->address_line_one,
              $Userinfo->address->address_line_two,
              $Userinfo->address->province,
              $Userinfo->address->city,
              $Userinfo->address->postal_code,
              $Userinfo->address->barangay,
        ];
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        // Exported Excel Headers, in order, which you should match them base on
        // manipulated data in above
        return [
            'id',
            'Organizational ID',
            'Last name',
            'First name',
            'Middle name',
            'Cellphone No.',
            'Tel No.',
            'Position in the organization',
            'Address 1',
            'Address 2.',
            'Province',
            'City',
            'Postal Code',
            'Barangay',
        ];
    }
}
```

```
Code for my model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserInfo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Address::class, 'address_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

```
Controller 
 public function BackupUser()
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');

    }
```

but when I try to run the program, it gives me an error of :

```
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header()
```

```
route.web
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'prevent-back-history'])->group(function () {

 Route::get('/export', [UserController::class, 'BackupUser'])->name('.export');

}
```

Did anyone know the to resolve this problem? Did i miss anything or make any mistakes? Any suggestion is highly appreciated . THankyou in advance

---

update

[image]

Comment: [1](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/call-to-undefined-method-binaryfileresponseheader-1), [2](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/2725) may be helpfull

Comment: can you post the whole stack trace

Comment: @ChinhNguyen Hello , I have already update my post

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli  , Thanks for the suggestion. The first  one works perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the middleware/preventHistory.php page, it should resolve the issue with excel Export.

```
$response = $next($request);

$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');

return $response;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).